# Keras - Adding loss to intermediate layer while ignoring the last layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've created the following Keras custom model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')
        self.lambda_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.argmax(x, axis=-1))

    
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_layer(inputs)
        x = self.lambda_layer(x)
        return x

    # A convenient way to get model summary 
    # and plot in subclassed api
    def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(raw_shape))
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], 
                              outputs=self.call(x))
```

[image]

The task is multi-class classification.
Model consists of a dense layer with softmax activation and a lambda layer as a post-processing unit that converts the dense output vector to a single value (predicted class).

The train targets are a one-hot encoded matrix like so:

```
[
   [0,0,0,0,1]
   [0,0,1,0,0]
   [0,0,0,1,0]
   [0,0,0,0,1]
]
```

It would be nice if I could define a `categorical_crossentropy` loss over the dense layer and ignore the lambda layer while still maintaining the functionality and outputting a single value when I call `model.predict(x)`.

**Please note**
My workspace environment doesn't allow me to use a custom training loop as suggested by @alonetogether excellent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a `Model.predict_classes` function that would replace the need for that lambda layer. But if it doesn't work:

---

There doesn't seem to be a way to do that without using one of these hacks:

- Two inputs (one is the groud truth values Y)
- Two outputs
- Two models

I'm quite convinced there is no other workaround for this.
So, I believe the "two models" version is the best for your case where you seem to "need" a model with single input, single output and `fit`.

Then I'd do this:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape_without_batch_size)    
loss_outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')(inputs)
final_outputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.argmax(x, axis=-1))(loss_outputs)

training_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, loss_outputs)
final_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, final_outputs)

training_model.compile(.....)
training_model.fit(....)

results = final_model.predict(...)
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. How would you wrap it all together in a single class?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a custom training loop, which is pretty straightforward IMO:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')
        self.lambda_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.argmax(x, axis=-1))

    
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_layer(inputs)
        x = self.lambda_layer(x)
        return x

    # A convenient way to get model summary 
    # and plot in subclassed api
    def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(raw_shape))
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], 
                              outputs=self.call(x))
        
n_classes = 5
model = MyModel(n_classes)
labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(tf.random.uniform((50, 1), maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32))
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 1)), labels)).batch(2)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model.layers[0](x_batch_train)
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

And prediction:

```
print(model.predict(tf.random.normal((1, 1))))
```

```
[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, my model is trained inside a framework that calls the model fit method and I cannot create a custom train loop.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention that you are using some framework and not Tensorflow / Keras directly ;)

Comment: Noted, I've updated my question. Can you think of another solution that might work with the current constraints?

Comment: Did you consider the the suggestions from Daniel? @ShlomiSchwartz

Comment: I  did, I  tried it and it works! I just need to encapsulate it in a wrapper class. Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to train the model on the normalized ground truth data, but I want to the model to output the "unnormalized" result.

What I did was add the "unnormalization" layer to the model and just add a wrapper around the loss function that renormalizes the output of the model for computing the loss only. This can be done in the compile function.

```
MyModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(output_mean, output_std, *args, **kwargs):
        self.output_mean = output_mean
        self.output_std = output_std
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def compile(optimizer, loss, *args, **kwargs):
        def loss_wrapper(y_true, y_pred):
            y_pred = (y_pred - self.output_mean) / self.output_std
            return loss(y_true, y_pred)
        super(MyModel, self).compile(optimizer, loss_wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I load the model later, I don't compile it so as to avoid the "Loss function 'loss_wrapper' not found" error

```
model.load_model("/model_path", compile=False)
```